# Proper use of Curl POST & GET

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I am using a CURL command to send strings of data to a form. My problem is that the form does not seem to be receiving the data.  It appears that either my `curl` command is not right or my `GET` in the form is not right.

In my `curl` I am using this format:

```
curl -X POST -d 'date=$now' http://127.0.0.1/log-entry.php
```

where `$now` is already declared above. In the receiving php form I retrieve the data using this command:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
```

BUT when I insert a print statement in the php for to check to see if it is received like:

```
print "Date $date\n";
```

that print statement is empty.  My understanding is that the curl is POSTing the data or string and the php is GETting that data from the url and assigning it to a string to be used as a value in the form.

Why do you think that the string data is not being sent? 
 Thanks

Comment: Since you're using POST, you have to use `$_POST['date']`, not `$_GET['date']`.

Comment: I did try that but the php form goes to error then??